# Is there full support for Scala in Spring MVC now?

Tags: scala, spring-mvc

Does Spring MVC now fully support using Scala as a language?

Are there any things that are problamatic or that take some special configuration/setup?

I personally just use spring mvc, IoC and then database helpers for hibernate (not really the security modules etc).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you are looking for any Scala specific features, but I have been using Spring MVC and Scala for over a year now.  You can see my sample applications [here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-mvc-jasper) and [here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-security-ajax) that use Scala and Spring MVC.

That said, the integration of Scala and Spring framework could be better as the framework does not take advantage of Scala features out of the box.  This is being addressed as part of the [Spring Scala project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-scala) which has reached release-candidate stage.  There is a [basic blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2012/12/10/introducing-spring-scala) explaining the project features and high level goals.